# How to add sidebar to kivy android app?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want a side bar for showing account details like: user name, profile etc. so i made an  rule in my kv file below how can i get this and what i did to get this this is also below: thanks in advance and rather then this program tips are always welcome.
this is my main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.animation import Animation

class MainScreen(FloatLayout):

    def menu_action(self):
        self.add_widget(SideBar())

class SideBar(FloatLayout):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print('inside side')
        else:
            print('outside side')

class testApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AccountMaintainerApp().run()
```

this is my kv file test.kv

```
<MainScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            size: root.size
            source: 'static/images/back.jpg'
    ActionBar:
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        background_color: 0, 0, 0, .1
        ActionView:
            use_separator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                app_icon: 'static/images/account.png'
                title: 'Account Maintainer'
                color: 0, 0, 0, 0 
                with_previous: False
            ActionButton:
                id: menu
                icon: 'static/images/menu.png'
                on_press: root.menu_action()

<SideBar>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, .6 
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    size_hint: (.8, 1)
    pos_hint: {'right': 1}
```

> on clicking menu button a sidebar open when i agan click on menu button a new side bar open
>   i want to disable it. How can i get this? and tell me if didn't
>   understand//

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you only want a sidebar to open on the first time the menu button is clicked. There are a couple ways to do this. One is to just keep track of whether a sidebar is already opened, and don't open a second. This can be done by changing your `MainScreen` class as below:

```
class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__()
        self.has_sidebar = False

    def menu_action(self):
        if not self.has_sidebar:
            print('adding sidebar')
            self.add_widget(SideBar())
            self.has_sidebar = True
        else:
            print('not adding sidebar')
```

Another way is to disable the button when it has been clicked. In that case, your `MainScreen` class would look like:

```
class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__()

    def menu_action(self):
        print('adding sidebar')
        self.add_widget(SideBar())
        self.ids['menu'].disabled = True
```